# Don't show red circle on review icon if we can't access that queue

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

Even after doing my daily 20 reviews in multiple queues, I'm still frequently seeing the red dot on the review icon. I'm not even sure the dot is because of queues I have access to (due to reputation limits).

Basically, it's useless to be showing me the dot, as I'm unable to review anything more (after a point). It would be great if this was fixed.

Bumping this because apparently people think it's an issue on my end. I just received the red dot, and the only queue I have access to currently is Late Answers, which was at 0. Reopen votes were at 146, which is likely what the dot is referring to.

This is *not* a duplicate of what it was marked as. That asker of that question has access to that queue as he has enough reputation. I do not, yet the red dot still lights up. I would appreciate it if the query was fixed, since it's essentially meaningless to me at this point. At the bare minimum, there should be an option to disable to dot until it is working properly.

Comment: I disagree. In that case, the user is still able to review queues if they want to. I'm not - I've already done 20 for the day. I've checked to see if it had just went below the quota for the dot, and all three that I am able to access were near zero (so probably didn't just drop below the quota).

Comment: The red dot is as much a signal to come help out as it is a signal that the workload is high, which should lower your expectations of how fast something will be closed/reopened/deleted/etc. Information is never truly useless.

Comment: But if I don't have access to any queues, surely that's useless to me.

Comment: The accepted answer of the duplicate actually answers your question, Shog9 had a good explanation on why the reopen votes at 146 could have caused the red dot.

Comment: It went straight to zero within ~3-4 seconds? I *highly* doubt that is the case.

Comment: This question and the duplicate is basically proposing the same bug about the red dot being glitchy (showing up when it shouldn't) for somewhat the same reasons, this is why I voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: It clearly hasn't been resolved, though, even if this is a duplicate. No idea who codes this kind of stuff, but it's something that presumably isn't cared too much about. It's not quite the same reasons, as I don't even have access to that queue, where the other question's asked did. To clarify, I don't have access to reopen votes, so it shouldn't even be triggering my red dot.

Comment: Yet again. Open it up and see reopens at 149. I don't have access to reopen votes! This should be disabled until it's fixed, or at least have an option to do so.