# Stop showing the Red Dot when there's nothing to review, and/or make the red-dot optional, delay partial dot delivery

Tags: feature-request, bug, review-queues, top-bar

### The gist of this question:

The dot will erroneously shown when there's nothing to review.
( Finished review tasks, or been banned. )

- I suggest to *fix* / improve it.
- I suggest to make it optional or can be temporarily disabled.
- I suggest to delay partial red-dot delivery, to avoid many people's fruitless click.

### Why it's not a duplicate:

[When I look at the review icon, I see red](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355233/5403468)
 -- This question is about the reasons of the red-dot not the problem or faults of it, and the accepted high-vote answer didn't answer OP's question in the last paragraph - which only relates to one point in this post and is not answered.

[Top bar “review needed red dot” showing, but no red dot in review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356697/5403468)
 -- This question do resemble my question, and I believed the high-vote answer at first. But my doubt was growing in the following days, the red-dot showed at days when I finished most or all review tasks. Also it didn't talk about the situation I met that the dot showed when I was banned from review. The question itself is mainly a bug-report aimed to one point while mine is a feature-request with other points.

[Don't show red circle on review icon if we can't access that queue [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359612/5403468)
 -- It's mainly at the *finished but still show* problem, and it was also falsely closed as duplicate, the *duplicate* of above one.

[Review's red dot in topbar is shown, but the queue that is in danger is grayed out for me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373788/5403468)
 -- Ditto. This question is not closed, I added my screenshots to it, however it's only for one situation, whereas my post covers more topics.

[Disable the red dot on the Review Queue (I'm distracted, but not interested)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358150/5403468)
 -- I'm not seeking to disable the dot completely, this question I've already read days ago. Disable it completely is somehow against the reviewing task, instead I want the dot system to improve thus falsely alert less people, so it's actually pro-reviewing task.

[“Attention required” red dot not shown in the review screens](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357662/5403468)
 -- Unrelated, while it's on topic of red-dot too, it seeks to keep showing the red-dot when reviewing.

While there're some other questions, they're similar to above ones, either on this point or that, and mostly a bug-report. While this is also a feature-request post, not a reason-finding one, not only bug-report, and not on one point only.

#### TL;DR:

As I said I'm not against reviewing, this is actually pro reviewing. (By avoid to make people like me to remove it entirely, or annoyed by it and stop contributing to the site.)

The Red dot will show up no matter I've finished the corresponding 20 reviews or not (even though it's not in the queues list, or my queues list already cleared).
It even showed up when I got temporarily banned from review.

I hope the system can improve a bit that don't show it when I actually cannot review the corresponding task.

And I hope the site can give an option to disable it, or temporary disable (like for 2 hours or so). (Kind of like Duolingo's *I can't speak now*)

Also hope the site can delay part of the red-dot delivery, like use some data-based algorithm determine how likely when people click it the clog will be gone already, only deliver the red-dot in time to part of the users which most-likely will dealing with it. When the clog is gone, then no need to show it on other people's screen, when it's still clogging, gradually add the dot to some screens.

As a person who has minor OCD, it really annoys me and distract me.
And it's a waste of time to us to click it when there's no review for us.
(I know I can use tampermonkey to remove it, but I still want it be an option there, and use tampermonkey to remove it entirely should be the last resort).

I'm not a native English Speaker, probably have wrong words and wrong sentences used, feel free to improve my question when you see an error or inaccuracy, or think it needs better formatting, thanks!

Comment: Possible (re)duplicate: [Top bar “review needed red dot” showing, but no red dot in review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356697/1287812)

Comment: @brasofilo No, it's not. That one I've read before. For one thing, It showed when I finished some or all tasks. For another, It showed when I cannot review (banned) today.

Comment: [I posted a feature request about this back in 2017.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/dont-show-red-circle-on-review-icon-if-we-cant-access-that-queue)

Comment: @jhpratt  Yeah, I read your question several days back and upvoted it. Your question is **also closed** as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Review's red dot in topbar is shown, but the queue that is in danger is grayed out for me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373788/reviews-red-dot-in-topbar-is-shown-but-the-queue-that-is-in-danger-is-grayed-o)