# Disable the red dot on the Review Queue and add a link to /review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, top-bar

Can the review queues menu please be changed as to not have the red dot on it when you are suspended or unwanted to review.

And can a link be put in to [stackoverflow.com/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) so you can review why you can't view the review queues instead of having to have the knowledge that it is at that exact address in stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop showing the Red Dot when there's nothing to review, and/or make the red-dot optional, delay partial dot delivery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379749/stop-showing-the-red-dot-when-theres-nothing-to-review-and-or-make-the-red-dot). The second part is probably a dupliate of [Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving?cb=1)

Comment: @BDL that is exactly the thing, seems like SO doesn't care [rude language removed –ed] as there seem to be posts from like 2017 about this